# Is this correlation zero?

Tags: random-variables, correlation

Let $\alpha(\vec{x})$ be a random function and $\vec{\beta}(\vec{x})$ be a continuous random vector such that $\alpha(\vec{x})\in (0, \infty)$, and mean of $\vec{\beta}$ is 0, i.e. $\langle\vec{\beta}\rangle=0$. Both $\alpha$ and $\vec{\beta}$ have Gaussian probability distribution, centered at 0. I am interested in the following correlation
$$C(\vec{x}_1, \vec{x}_2)=\langle \vec{\nabla}_{\vec{x}_1}\alpha(\vec{x}_1)\cdot\vec{\beta}(\vec{x}_2)\rangle~,$$
where $\nabla$ os the gradient and $\vec{x}_1$, and $\vec{x}_2$ are two dimensional vector positions. 
My question is: can I write $$C(\vec{x}_1, \vec{x}_2)=\vec{\nabla}_{\vec{x}_1}\cdot\langle\alpha(\vec{x}_1)\vec{\beta}(\vec{x}_2)\rangle~?$$
If yes, does this mean that $C(\vec{x}_1, \vec{x}_2)=0$, as $\langle\vec{\beta}\rangle=0$, while $\alpha$ is purely positive?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean when you say, eg, that $\alpha(\vec{x})$ is a continuous random variable.  Do you mean $\alpha$ is a random function, and $\vec{x}$ is its argument?  What does "continuous" mean in this context.  What do you know about the probability distribution of $\alpha$ or or $\alpha(\vec{x})$?

Comment: Sorry, I meant $\alpha$ is a random function and $\vec{x}$ is its argument. The PDF of both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is Gaussian.

Comment: How can $\alpha$ be both "purely positive" and Gaussian centered at $0$?